# Reduce the teeth showed only ten results

Tags: ios, swift

This class show  autoCompleteTextField ,but if you write in textField name doctor show in variable doctors to much 
results  how to reduce the teeth showed only ten results

```
import UIKit
class DoctorsDataSource: NSObject, MLPAutoCompleteTextFieldDataSource {

    var listDoctors=[String]()

    func autoCompleteTextField(textField: MLPAutoCompleteTextField!, possibleCompletionsForString string: String!, completionHandler handler: ([AnyObject]!) -> ()) {


        let appDelegate: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var requestParameters: [NSObject:AnyObject] = [NSObject: AnyObject]()

        requestParameters["name"] = textField.text
        requestParameters["country"]="1"
        requestParameters["weight"] = "iphone_search_doctors"
        requestParameters["today"] = "true"

        appDelegate.objectManager.getObjectsAtPath("/doctors", parameters: requestParameters, success: {
            (rkoperation: RKObjectRequestOperation!, rkmap: RKMappingResult!) -> Void in


            if let doctors = rkmap.array() as? [Doctor]  {
                for doctor: Doctor in doctors {

                    self.listDoctors.append("\(doctor.firstname) \(doctor.lastname)")
                }
            }
            handler(self.listDoctors)
            }, failure: {
                (rkoperation: RKObjectRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                print("Load filed with error: @", error!)
                self.performSelectorOnMainThread(#selector(AppDelegate.showFetchError), withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in

```
        for doctor: Doctor in doctors {
            self.listDoctors.append("\(doctor.firstname) \(doctor.lastname)")
        }
```

You are adding all doctors list in the `listDoctors`, if you want to show only 10, you can add a variable to count how manny you have already added and then break when hit this number, a sample of this, is the following code:

```
    var doctorCount = 0
    for doctor: Doctor in doctors {

        if doctorCount++ == 10{
            break
        }

        self.listDoctors.append("\(doctor.firstname) \(doctor.lastname)")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just simply use following of one line code

```
    let Uptocount = 10
    var ArrTopTenRecord = self.listDoctors.prefix(Uptocount) 
    print(" array is \(ArrTopTenRecord)")
```

After that return `ArrTopTenRecord` for show the result.